# Effective Date of IRS's 1099 Reporting Limit Decrease

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, form-1099

For roughly a decade payment processors like paypal weren't required to 1099 you unless you made $20,000 & 200+ transactions. But that has been decreased to $600, so my question is what year will be the first year in which this is applied? Will this be applied for 2021? I.e. If in 2021 $600 is processed through a paypal account will paypal be required to 1099 that account? Or will it remain $20,000 until 2022? I.e. [this page](https://www.pwc.com/us/en/services/tax/library/american-rescue-plan-act-lowers-form-1099k-reporting-threshold.html) states that payment processors like paypal will only 1099 accounts processing $600 starting in 2022, but some other sources have other information.

Comment: 1099-K reporting only started in 2012 (for 2011), exactly one decade not plural.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there is some ambiguity. From [Sovos](https://sovos.com/blog/trr/stimulus-bill-includes-change-to-1099-k-reporting-threshold/):

> While the threshold change is clear, the effective date of the change
> is not. Specifically, the bill indicates that the change “shall apply
> to returns for calendar years beginning after December 31, 2021.” It
> seems so simple – but in practice, I’ve already received these two
> questions:
>
> 1. Does this mean that the change is effective for returns filed after
>    December 31, 2021? If so, this means that the Forms 1099-K for the
>    2021 calendar year are impacted.
> 2. Does this mean that the change is
>    effective for returns issued after December 31, 2021? If so, this
>    means that the Forms 1099-K for the 2022 calendar year are impacted.
>
> As I told Liz Farmer at Forbes, the budget analysis for the Act
> includes expected increases in tax revenue associated with this change
> for Fiscal Year 2022 which is the calendar year 2023. Therefore, I
> interpret the second scenario is correct – so returns issued for the
> 2022 calendar year that are filed in early 2023 are impacted.
>
> I guess we’ll know for sure when the IRS releases follow-up
> communications.

This seems logical to me, and most sources agree: the change is for 2022 transactions, reported in 2023. But there's always a chance the IRS surprises us.

Comment: 1099-series and related forms _are_ returns, but _information_ returns rather than _tax_ returns. See e.g. https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/a-guide-to-information-returns . But a return 'for' year Y always means a return containing data about transactions or events in year Y and is almost always filed in year Y+1.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Good to know, thanks. I've removed this sentence from my answer.